# create specific scope HABTM Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a **User model** and a **Conversation model**. User has many conversations and Conversation has many users, so I use **has_and_belongs_to_many** relationship through join table **:conversations_users**. I use the method to return the conversation between specific users (by user id):

```
def find_conversation_between_users(ids)
  conversation = nil
  conversations = Conversation.all

  if conversations.present?
    conversations.each do |conv|
      next unless conv.user_ids == ids.sort

      conversation = conv
    end
  end
end


class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :conversations
end
```

It works but it won't be efficient if we would have thousands of conversations and it will take too much time to iterate over each of them.
So I try to create the scope that returns the specific conversation by related user_ids [1 , 2, 3].

```
scope :by_user_id, ->(user_ids) { joins(:conversations_users).where([ conversations_users: { user_id: user_ids } ]) }
```

But it does not works.

Comment: Would you be ready to change to `has_many: through`? If yes, I think I could give you solution. Basically there are  no change in tables - just need to create `ConversationsUser` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  scope :by_user_id, ->(ids) { joins(:users).where(users: { id: ids }).group(:id).having("count(*) >= ?", ids.size) }
end
```

Comment: It works but incorrectly. For example, if I have: 
"Created the conversation with id=1 that has [1, 2] user_ids."
"Created the conversation with id=2 that has [2, 3] user_ids."
"Created the conversation with id=3 that has [1, 4] user_ids."
and perform Conversation.by_user_id([1,2]), it returns conversations with ids: **1, 3, 1, 2**. but I need only with id **1**.

Comment: @PashaBratanov Hmm now I understand the problem. I updated the answer.

Comment: @PashaBratanov You're welcome. Would you mark my answer as an answer and upvote it :)